# Does Verilator support SystemVerilog libraries?

Tags: system-verilog, verilator

When compiling RTL from multiple sources it is normal to compile them into separate SystemVerilog libraries.  Doing this means they cannot interfere with each other, and you can compile multiple different modules with the same name into different libraries.

SystemVerilog configurations are used to select which library to elaborate a module from.  As described in the SV LRM 2017 (33 Configuring the contents of a design).  E.g.

```
config cfg1; // specify rtl adder for top.a1, gate-level adder for top.a2
  design rtlLib.top;
  default liblist rtlLib;
  instance top.a2 liblist gateLib;
endconfig
```

Does Verilator support compilation into separate libraries like the commercial simulators?

Comment: Have you tried it with verilator? Configs/libraries are a standard part of verilog 2001, well before system verilog and usually are referenced as v2k libraries.

Comment: Yeah.  I get 'Unsupported: Verilog 2001-config reserved word not implemented: design' etc.  I am using '+1800-2017ext+sv' which, I think, should enable the latest SV which should include the 20 year old Verilog I think.  Signs aren't good are they but I'm not confident that I am using the correct switches, so I want to know whether it's possible or not.

Comment: So, you got the answer to your question then. You do not need the latest sv standard. Try to ask it at verilator forum.

Answer (score -1):

No and it never will.

Chapter 33 of the LRM is specifically procluded from being supported by Verilator.  See here: https://github.com/verilator/verilator/blob/master/docs/internals.rst#never-features